# EF core2.1 Count/Distinct

Tags: c#-6.0, sql-server-2017, ef-core-2.1

query is an *IQueryable* that contain many join and conditions.

```
var total = await query.Select(p=>p.Id).Distinct().CountAsync();
```

sql generated by EF Core 2.1 :

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT [Id]
       FROM (many join and condition)
     ) as [t]
```

the query take about **8 second** to return the total.

I change my sql query manually to this:

```
 SELECT COUNT(distinct Id)
 From (many join and condition)
```

and the query take **3 second**

How to re-write my linq query to generate ***count(distinct id)*** instead of ***select count(*) from (...)***

Comment: There is no LINQ query construct which translates to SQL `count(distinct expr)`. And normally it doesn't matter - are you using MySQL?

Comment: @IvanStoev I’m using sql server

Comment: why `OrderBy` ?

Comment: i deleted the `OrderBy` and i save 1 second, i will update my post thanks @Petaflop

Comment: If your *LINQ* query has many joins and conditions something is seriously wrong. LINQ isn't a replacement for SQL, it works on *entities* that should have relations and navigation properties. You shouldn't need to use JOINs. ORMs in generate are *not* meant for reporting queries. Create a view with the reporting query you want instead of trying to replicate it in LINQ. Or execute a raw SQL statement directly